# Does being well approximated by a polynomial characterize higher differentiability?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ admits a polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda_k(x-a)^k$ of degree $\leq n$ satisfying $f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda_k(x-a)^k\in \mathrm o(|x-a|^n)$ as $x\to a$. Then dividing by powers of $(x-a)$ shows

$$\begin{aligned}\lambda_0 & =\lim_{x\to a}fx, \\ \lambda_1 & =\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{fx-\lambda_0}{x-a}, \\ \lambda _2 & =\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{fx-fa-\lambda_1(x-a)}{(x-a)^2}=\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{\tfrac{fx-fa}{x-a}-\lambda_1}{x-a}, \\  & \vdots \\ \lambda_n & = \lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{fx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\lambda_k(x-a)^k}{(x-a)^n}. \end{aligned}$$

Thus the asymptotic condition determines the polynomial, so it is unique when it exists. If $f$ is furthermore continuous at $x=a$ then $\lambda_0=fa$ whence $\lambda_1=f^\prime(a)$.

---

If $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $x=a$ then Peano's form of Taylor's theorem tells us $R^n_af\in \mathrm o(|x-a|^n)$ as $x\to a$. Here $R^n_af(x)=f(x)-j^n_af(x)$ and $$j^n_af(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\tfrac 1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k$$ is the $n^\text{th}$ order Taylor series of $f$ about $x=a$.

By uniqueness we therefore have $\lambda_k=\tfrac 1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)$. For instance taking $k=0,1,2$ gives $$\tfrac 12f^{(2)}(a)=\lambda _2  =\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{fx-fa-f^\prime(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^2}=\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{\tfrac{fx-fa}{x-a}-f^\prime(a)}{x-a}.$$

---

I am interested in the converse: are continuous maps which are well approximated by a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ necessarily $n$-times differentiable?

**Question.** Suppose $f$ is continuous and admits a polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda_k(x-a)^k$ of degree $\leq n$ satisfying $f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda_k(x-a)^k\in \mathrm o(|x-a|^n)$ as $x\to a$. Does it follow that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $x=a$, with $\lambda_k=\tfrac 1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)$?

Already for $k=2$ this amounts to the assertion$$\tfrac 12f^{(2)}(a)=\lambda _2  =\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{fx-fa-f^\prime(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^2}=\lim_{x\to a}\tfrac{\tfrac{fx-fa}{x-a}-f^\prime(a)}{x-a}.$$ This is not obvious at all to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you cannot reclaim any information about  any neighborhood of $a$. So basically, $f$ may not even be differentiable at any neighborhood of $a$, so definitely it cannot be twice-differentiable. Consider the following example:
$$f(x)=W(x)\cdot e^{-\frac1{x^2}}  $$
Where $W$ is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). $W$ is known to be non-differentiable at any point. However, $W$ is bounded, and so
$$ f(x)=o(x^n),\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
just as $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is. So, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ **but**
it is non differentiable at any other point. Therefore, we cannot even ask the question whether it is twice differentiable at $0$.